# Google Colab Output hidden when printing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

When saving the Jupyter Notebook output using nbconvert on google colab some of the output cells are hidden and I get the following message:

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input "my_notebook.ipynb"'
```

in the HTML file i get:

```
Output hidden; open https://colab.research.google.com to view.
```

Do you know how to make sure the output is not hidden?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe these cells needs to run code to show output - but HTML can't run it and it will never show output.  Do you see these cells when you open in Colab without running cells? Maybe you have to first run all cells and then save notebook?

Comment: Yes I do have the cells, but the only cells that are hidden are the cells with long output

Comment: I have the same problem, I do not need to run the cells to see the output after opening the .ipynb, but when I save them, it just prints the output hidden message

Comment: And the same is true for printing to PDF

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the problem is due to an unsupported format. If the output is in image format, you may want to try using Matplotlib to display the image.

Try the following steps

1.

`!pip install Pillow matplotlib`

2.

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image_path = 'path_to_your_image_file.jpg'
image = Image.open(image_path)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```